# EF and LINK query not giving all table values in "select"

Tags: linq, entity-framework

How do I use a column in the "where" that I haven't inluded in the "select"? The "where" method isn't showing me all the columns in my SQL Server table, only the 3 in the select statement. I need to do the select based on a different column in the table:

```
using (var context = new URIntakeEntities())
{
    return context.Claims.Select(
        u => new Models.Claim
        {
            ClaimNumber = u.ClaimNumber,
            DateOfInjury = u.DateOfInjury,
            Denied = u.Denied
        }).Where(u => u.?????).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move your `where` statement before the `select statement`.

```
using (var context = new URIntakeEntities())
{
    return context.Claims.Where(u=> u.?????).Select(
        u => new Models.Claim
        {
            ClaimNumber = u.ClaimNumber,
            DateOfInjury = u.DateOfInjury,
            Denied = u.Denied
        }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! I get it. By putting the "select" first, I'm reducing the columns that show up in subsequent methods. That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> How do I use a column in the "where" that I haven't included in the
>   "select"?

You can't. Where is applied on a current type of sequence. So, you should apply filter before projecting result:

```
using (var context = new URIntakeEntities())
{
    return context.Claims
                  .Where(u => u.?????)
                  .Select(u => new Models.Claim 
                   {
                       ClaimNumber = u.ClaimNumber,
                       DateOfInjury = u.DateOfInjury,
                       Denied = u.Denied
                   }).ToList();
}
```